# Creating a list of positions of a substring within a string (DNA) (Python 3)

Tags: python, string, indexing, substring, bioinformatics

I am doing a bioinformatics course and I am trying to write *a function to find all occurrences of a substring within a string*.

```
def find_match(s, t):
  """Returns a list of all positions of a substring t in string s.

  Takes two arguments: s & t.
  """
  occurrences = []
  for i in range(len(s)-len(t)+1): # loop over alignment
    match = True
    for j in range(len(t)): # loop over characters
            if s[i+j] != t[j]:  # compare characters
                match = False   # mismatch
                break
            if match:   # allchars matched
                occurrences.append(i)

  return(occurrences)
    

print(find_match("GATATATGCATATACTT", "ATAT")) # [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 13]
print(find_match("AUGCUUCAGAAAGGUCUUACG", "U")) # [1, 4, 5, 14, 16, 17]
```

The output above should exactly match the following:

[2, 4, 10]

[2, 5, 6, 15, 17, 18]

How can I fix this? Preferably without using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you badly indented the code, the

```py
if match:
```

has to be outside of the inner cycle.

```py
def find_match(s, t):
    """Returns a list of all positions of a substring t in string s.

      Takes two arguments: s & t.
    """
    occurrences = []
    for i in range(len(s)-len(t)+1): # loop over alignment
        match = True
        for j in range(len(t)): # loop over characters
            if s[i+j] != t[j]:  # compare characters
                match = False   # mismatch
                break
        if match: # <--- This shouldn't be inside the inner for cycle
            occurrences.append(i + 1)

    return occurrences
    

print(find_match("GATATATGCATATACTT", "ATAT")) # [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 13]
print(find_match("AUGCUUCAGAAAGGUCUUACG", "U")) # [1, 4, 5, 14, 16, 17]
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! I spent too much time on this simple mistake, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`find`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-string-methods/python-string-find/),

```
def find_match(s, t):
    return list(set([s.find(t, i)+1 for i in range(len(s)-1) if s.find(t, i) != -1]))
```

Output:

```
In [1]: find_match("AUGCUUCAGAAAGGUCUUACG", "U")
Out[1]: [2, 5, 6, 15, 17, 18]

In [2]: find_match("GATATATGCATATACTT", 'ATAT')
Out[2]: [2, 10, 4]
```

Find will return the position of the substring. So iterate through the index and pass that into the `str.find` method. If the substring does not exist `find` will return `-1`. So it needs to filter out.

```
In [1]: "GATATATGCATATACTT".find('ATAT', 0)
Out[1]: 1
```

Comment: Nice alternative! Why does it have a different order for the 2nd output though?

Comment: @Meetrix It's due to the `set` conversion (uses to remove the duplicates). If you need to get the sort you can use `sorted`.